# change table row background-color dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with folllowing attributes

- Product name
- price
- quantity
- description

I want to change table row color based on the quantity as soon as page loads if quantity<5 then red if quantity >5 and <15 then blue and >15 green
I have the following javascript

```js
function quantityfunc(quantity) {
  var x = document.getElemetById("tablerow")
  var y = quantity;
  if (y <= 5) {
    x.class = "warning";
  } else if (y > 5 && y < 15) {
    x.class = "info";
  } else {
    x.class = "success";
  }

}
```

```html
<tbody>
  <c:forEach items="${products }" var="p" quantityfunc(${p.quantity})>
    <tr id="tablerow">
      <td>${p.productName}</td>
      <td>${p.price}</td>
      <td>${p.quantity}</td>
      <td>${p.description}</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

i dont know how to invoke the function to execute the code

Comment: An element id should be unique but it looks like you're pushing out several `<tr id="tablerow">`

Comment: Can't you just loop through that after the documents load?